# How can I pause other background musics when my own background app starts to play a song(ionic project)?

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm building an ionic project which beeps for the certain event.
It should stop background songs when it starts to play.
The previous version worked perfect excepting that it didn't beep when the app was in background.
So I added the plugin to run the app in the background mode.

cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git

And in the code I added the block to make my app run in the background mode.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // Android customization
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text:'...'});
    // Enable background mode
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

    // Called when background mode has been activated
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Modify the currently displayed notification
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.configure({
                text:'Running in background for more than 5s now.'
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
}, false);
```

Now the app beeps even if it is in background mode which is great.
But unfortunately now it doesn't pause other background musics like it did before.
The music of my app and other background musics are mixed now.
Beep on the song!

I'm testing it on iOS.
Simply put, I can't find a way to pause other background musics when my beep starts to run in background mode.
Is it even possible?
or Background apps can't interrupt each other?

I appreciate all your inputs.